# Normal Sylow-p Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that given a group $G$, if $P \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G), K \leq P \lhd G$, then $K \lhd G$? If so, can I see a proof?

Comment: If that was the case then any subgroup of a $p$-group would be normal in it. (which is obviously not true)

Comment: No, it is wrong in general: $K$ might be a  non-normal  subgroup of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer, here is *Mark*'s:

> If that was the case then any subgroup of a $p$-group would be normal in it (which is obviously not true).